# Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5 - bower.json

Tags: asp.net, proxy, bower, visual-studio-2015

I have two issues I am facing with the VS 2015 CTP 5 as of now with regard to bower. I have hosted VPC on Virtual Box on my local office PC with Windows Server 2012 R2 with latest updates.

**Issue #1**

Using the default project template, when I try restoring the bower package using the solution explorer I got the following error,

[image]

As a work around, upon much searching the net, I added the .bowerrc file at the same level of the bower.json file with the following entry exactly as it is below,

```
{
    "proxy": "http://<host>:<port>"
}
```

The above section being added to the .bowerrc file, just magically enabled bower to download the packages using **https://** instead of **git://**

Any explanation would be very helpful.

**Issue #2**

Having solved Issue #1, I am however unable to get intelliSense withing the bower.json file for **version numbers** as shown below, and currently have no solution of how to enable it.

[image]

From what I see, I believe this is caused due to me being behind a proxy at my work place. However it would be great if any of you could recommend a solution for me to get this working with the proxy as I don't seem to see any articles realted to this.